# Prevent activity run from recent app list in android

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have an activity `A` which start when a custom broadcast received. This activity is not the launcher activity.

## receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context,A.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

A receive the intent value (Intent has some values) and full fill some task. The whole procedure is working fine.

Problem is that, when i open recent application list (Long press home button) this activity appears (not a launcher activity) and when i click on it, activity start with intent value !!. So i can't check is this activity start from broadcast receiver or from other.

How can i fix this?? This activity should only start when a broadcast receive.

## Edit

Manifest

```
android:name".A"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
android:noHistory="true"
android:taskAffinity=""
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you try:

android:name".A"

android:excludeFromRecents="true"

This will prevent your activity from being displayed in recent list.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude)

when your activity is the root of a new task, it will not appear in the recent list. if it's not the root , try adding `taskAffinity` property.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. It doesn't work. I have added manifest in question. I also add taskAffinity="MainActivity" but no luck

Comment: did you add `android:excludeFromRecents` ?